# R - How to store custom objects in a matrix (or similar structure)?

Tags: r, class, object, matrix

I'm trying to fill a matrix with objects of a custom class. But it seems like this wouldn't work. Here's my attempt:

```
setClass('Person', representation(name = 'character', age = 'numeric'))

m = matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 10)

m[1, 1] = 42 #works

john = new('Person', name = 'John Smith', age = 42)

m[1, 1] = john #Error in m[1, 1] = john : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Am I missing something or is `matrix` just the wrong tool for this? If  so, what should I use instead?

Comment: I think that matrix might be the wrong tool, as a matrix is an atomic type. For  more info on data structures (and s4 classes) I'd recommend looking here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a data frame, you can store the object as a list (column is coerced to a list variable):

```
setClass('Person', representation(name = 'character', age = 'numeric'))

m = as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 10))

m[1, 1] = 42 #works

john = new('Person', name = 'John Smith', age = 42)

m[1, 1] = list(list(john))
```

Comment: I'd actually like to keep the cell perspective, it makes things a lot easier to handle than with lists. Is there a way to get from and set to a 2d object without having to deal with lists? I wouldn't mind if it was something different than a `matrix` or a `data.frame`.

Comment: I'm not sure the data structure you're describing exists.  Your other option may be to store the new class as a character string and convert it back later.

Comment: Alright, I'd rather stick with your solution then. ^_^ Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It probably isn't the right tool. You can however force things into matrices if you have a `list()` for each cell, but it's often not ideal. Consider:

```
m <- matrix(list(), nrow=10, ncol=10)
m[1, 1] = list(john) 
m[1, 1]
#[[1]]
#An object of class "Person"
#Slot "name":
#[1] "John Smith"
#
#Slot "age":
#[1] 42
```